# How to convert data to double with more than one character ? [swift]

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, uint

I am trying to convert data from my Arduino bluetooth device to a Double. So I write this function :

```
 func convert(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Double {

    guard let arduinoData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
    let byteArray = [UInt8](arduinoData)

//  print(characteristicData as NSData)

    return Double(byteArray[0])
}
```

I receive character ascii from my arduino. So this code works for numbers from 0 to 9. But I want to receive value like 300.207

I would like to know if it was possible to read 7 octets in succession to place them in a single double ?

I try with the code bellow to read the first octet and the seconde but I have this error : Thread 1 : Fatal error: Index out of range

```
func convert(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Double {
        guard let arduinoData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
        let byteArray = [UInt8](arduinoData)

        return Double(byteArray[0]) + Double(byteArray[1])
    }
```

Thanks ( I am a beginner )

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773367/convert-byte-array-to-double-in-swift ?

Comment: In what format is the value sent? Show the output of `print(arduinoData as NSData)`  .

Comment: I receive this :

<01>
Mmhg: 49 mmhg
<34>
Mmhg: 52 mmhg

Comment: jake I have already seen his posts. But I have trouble understanding the proposed solutions

Comment: Take a look at this aswer. Great explanation how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/2243451